# RSET pin function of RTL8211E

Tags: phy

I'm using Realtek's ethernet PHY RTL8211E, but can't figure out what's the purpose of pin 'RSET', and how to connect it. The only datasheet I can find is
[here](http://download3.dvd-driver.cz/realtek/datasheets/pdf/rtl8211e%28g%29-vb%28vl%29-cg_datasheet_1.6.pdf).

It's wired I can't get that datasheet from the official web page about [RTL8211E/EG](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=14&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=279).

So, anyone can give some informations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Realtek's ethernet PHY RTL8211E, but can't figure out what's the purpose of pin 'RSET', and how to connect it. The only datasheet I can find is here.

On page 12 of the datasheet you provided, it says:

[image]

And if you look at the high level circuit diagram on page 5, it shows the pin feeds a bandgap stage. So it looks like the resistor is part of the bandgap reference voltage generation for the internal voltage regulator.

The bandgap stage [(see here)](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=bandgap.reference) offers a very precise voltage reference so that the voltage regulator provides a more stable output.

This specific datasheet doesn't specify what the value for the RSET resistor should be. But after a bit of looking around, I found another [datasheet, page 8](http://file:///C:/Users/CAE/Downloads/pdf_RTL8305NB-Realtek.pdf) for a Realtek IC (PHY) which uses a bandgap reference as well and they use a value of 2.49k for that resistor.

The regulator voltages are about the same for both ICs (1.05V vs 1.0V). That may be a good place to start

[image].

Comment: The bandgap should provide a stable reference regardless of regulator voltage (a commonly exploited property). The value of the resistor would instead be chosen based on the driver topology of the transceiver. I think that the very precise voltage from the bandgap is passed through Rset and the resulting highly stable current is used (via a current mirror) for the current steering that is part of the differential transceiver drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that "not for public release" stamp on the datasheet? Also the note that says "for development partners only"? It means that you probably have to sign an NDA in order to get the datasheet from realtek and have an agreement with them about what you're building, etc. Things like gigabit transceivers are sensitive and valuable IP and so companies like to control who accesses it.

Anyway, I can hazard a guess at what RSET does based on a similar looking situation with the [(public) TI TUSB7340 USB 3.0 Host Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb7320.pdf): It requires a precision resistor of a particular value which is used to calibrate the precise currents required for high speed differential signaling terminations inside the chip. You will also find similar resistors on Xilinx FPGAs which have the [7-series GPT Hard IP](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug482_7Series_GTP_Transceivers.pdf) (look for mentions of "RCAL") and also on PCI Express switches. You need to find out exactly what value is required before you can even hope to get the chip to work properly.

Comment: OK, I think I should say bye to Realtek, and find a replacement from Marvell.

Comment: yeah, or clone someone elses design that uses that chip.